# Httpd Directory read permissions issue

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-web-services, httpd

In my scenario ,I need the 'httpd' directory in '/var/log/' to be readable by the users in 'devs' group (Amazon Linux 2)
Could anyone guide me how to accomplish this?

We have a few developers who maintain the system and I want them to easily read the log files in /var/log/httpd without needing root access.

```
[root@ip-10-0-10-165 httpd]# getfacl /var/log/httpd
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/log/httpd
# owner: root
# group: devs
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
```

can this will help ??

```
  chmod -R go+r /var/log/httpd
 `chmod -R go+rX /var/log/httpd`
```

or

```
    [root@ip-10-0-10-165 httpd]# ls -la
total 48
drwx------ 19 root   devs   4096 Apr  3 03:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root   devs   4096 Apr  8 07:45 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      0 Feb 15 14:55 access_log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   devs     41 Mar  1 20:44 u1-dev.qwerty.com
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   1648 Apr  3 03:42 error_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    883 Mar 13 03:41 error_log-20220313
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   devs     41 Mar  1 20:44 u4-dev.qwerty.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     41 Mar  1 20:44 langs.qwerty.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   devs     41 Mar  1 20:44 u8-dev3.qwerty.com
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      0 Feb 15 14:55 ssl_access_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    314 Apr  3 03:42 ssl_error_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    157 Mar  6 03:50 ssl_error_log-20220313
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      0 Feb 15 14:55 ssl_request_log
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache  253 Apr  3 03:42 www.qwerty.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   devs     41 Mar  1 20:44 u13-dev.qwerty.com
[root@ip-10-0-20-173 httpd]#
```

or this will work

```
setfacl -m g:devs:rx httpd/
```

How to  modifying those permission set?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit the `sudo` configuration, to allow everybody in the dev group access to specific files like this:

```
%devs ALL = (root:root) NOPASSWD: /var/log/httpd
```

Edit: Another, way easier and safer option would be to give the file 644 permissions with `chmod 644 /var/log/httpd`, however this means that *everybody* can read the file who has access to the server.

Comment: This `sudo` entry gives everybody in the devs group permissions to run the command `/var/log/httpd`. Not what the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the best way to do this is

```
chgrp -R apache /var/log/httpd
chmod 02750 /var/log/httpd
chmod 0640 /var/log/httpd/*
```

Add all users in the `dev` group to group apache. Modify `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd` so that new log files are created in the right group, e.g.,

```
create 0640 root apache
```

Comment: Is this also work ? chmod go+rX /var/log/httpd

Comment: doneal24, can you describe a bit with example , Chmod 2750 can read can't write and can execute. (O)thers can't read, can't write and can't execute. right ? how  to modify /etc/logrotate.d/httpd ?